# How to call js for appropriate element

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Can't how to deal with my problem: part of view are hidden, when page is loaded.

Here is this part:

```
  <table>
  <% @websites.each do |website| %>
    <%if (current_user.id == website.user_id)%>
    <tr>
<td>  <%= link_to(image_tag("/images/caret-horizontal.png", id: "caret-horizontal"), '#') %> </td>
<td>  <h4><%= website.name %></h4> </td>
 </tr>
   </table>
 <table id="<%= website.id %>"> // or can be like this:
//I don't what variant is better
 <table id="table-data" data-id="<%= website.id %>">>
 <tr >

   <td >
 <%= website.url %>
   </td>

  </tr>
 <tr>

 <td >
 <%= website.category  %>

 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>

 <td><%= website.language %></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

And I can get attributes in JavaScript like this(thanks to good people):

```
   var yourWebsiteId = $("#table-data").attr("data-id");
```

How I can choose approriate element and show it? I should use getElementById or something like this, but I don't know exactly how to do it.

Please help me, if you can.

Comment: What is the "appropriate element"? You have nested `<td>`s, by the way.

Comment: Is it clear now? I want to show table with website.id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$("#table-data").show()

You can find information on this from [here](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

$("#table-data") gets a reference to the part of the dom you are trying to access (# denotes id, . denotes class), once you have a reference you can then call any jquery operation you want on it

Comment: Wait a minute please, if I have questions, ok?